# How can i install my Lg tv app with an other method than USB

Tags: smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

I writ a LG smart tv app for a client in franche so i need to test it in real tv the probleme LG has just one methode for test the app its by USB or put the app in LG WORLD STOR for me i can't give my app to my client in the usb to test it in hise tv so can sombody show me an other method.
Pleas help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace one of Premium Apps by DNS spoofing.

- select any app
- find out it URL
- create corresponding record in your DNS server, wich will resolve app host to your server
- specify your DNS server in TV Network settings
- test your app

Comment: I'm so sorry i didnt see your answer i have just seen it thanks a loooooooooooooooooooooooot